# Business Objects - Business View - Merge Databases

Tags: database, view, merge

I have the same system, with the same database model in 6 different servers.

I'm able to create a single business view for them, since they have the same tables, but I need to create 6 different connections to choose the source DB.

So, when we need a report I have to make it 6 times, each one using a different connection.

Is there a way to merge the tables of these DBs to one single DB connection, so that with one report i'm able to get all the information I need?

I mean, is it possible to do with the Business View framework, without having to rely on ETL and Data Warehouse solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are speaking of a BI environment. You could establish the db connections on the db-server and create a db-view on one db-server.
That would be your master server, where you set up on.